# Database Design: Supertypes and Subtypes

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

So I'm doing a weekly task and am a little stumped. Basically doing a database logical model for a Restaurant menu.

I'm trying to record a Menu with 3 different types so I've set it up as:

MENU

```
With 3 subtypes: 
Main, Entree, Dessert
```

With main, entree and dessert having their own subtypes.
However, I only have one subtype option for my Desserts which is it is either Lactose Free or not.

What would be the best way to set this up? It is possible to have a a single subtype?

Comment: And this is for both MySQL and MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: sorry, i've fixed it now. First time using stack overflow

Comment: SQL Developer is a client/IDE and doesn't dictate which database you're using - is it actually Oracle, or one of the others you originally tagged? I'm also not sure if you're talking about normal relational tables, or [object types and subtype](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjint.htm#ADOBJ001).